# What is the meaning of converted/unconverted photons?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, terminology

ATLAS and CMS sometimes refer to converted or unconverted photons, but I could not find the meaning of these two terms. I assume they have something to do with conversion of the photon to electron-poitron pairs. It can't be after the ECAL since it is something like 20+ radiation lengths long...

My guess is that the term `converted' photon refers to a photon that has pair produced before the ECAL (say in the tracker) and that 'unconverted' photons only pair produce in the ECAL. Can someone confirm this guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is right. The ATLAS "twiki" has some nice event displays with converted photon candidates : https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/AtlasPublic/EventDisplaysFromHiggsSearches